# How to get Search Icon in Vscode

Tags: visual-studio-code

I want to search keywords in all files. but I don't have the following icon in my VScode. What's the name of plugin?
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to Right click the sidebar:

[image: screenshot showing the right click options]

Comment: I pressed 'CTRL+Shift+F' and it enabled the search feature. Thankssssssssss.

Answer (score 0):

Possibly CTRL+Shift+F. This might toggle the visibility of the search bar.

Comment: Didn't worked!!!!